# How can I my activity get notified what changes user made?

Tags: android

In my activity, i have a ListPreference which pops up a dialog and allow to select a value for a preference.

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="limit"
    android:title="@string/limit_label"
    android:entries="@array/limit_label"
    android:entryValues="@array/limit_values"
    android:defaultValue="@string/default_limit"
/>
```

Can you please tell me if there is a call back function which I get notified what user has selected in the LIstPreference?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%28android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%29) for changes.